# .map() function and deleting a row from a table with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a problem wrapping my head around the .map() function as it relates to ReactJS. In practice, I have a table onto which I can add rows, but deleting a row by passing the index of the row is just not working. Here's what I have; can anyone clear up what I'm doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class CommentList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            comments: []
        };
        this.handleCommentDelete = this.handleCommentDelete.bind(this);
    }
    handleCommentDelete(i) {
        alert('i = ' + i);
        let comments = [...this.state.comments];
        comments.splice(i, 1);
        this.setState({
            comments: comments
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <table className="commentList">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.props.data.map((comment, i) => {
                            return (
                                <tr className="comment" key={i}>
                                    <td className="commentId">{comment.Id}</td>
                                    <td className="commentName">{comment.Name}</td>
                                    <td className="commentPhone">{comment.Phone}</td>
                                    <td className="commentEmail">{comment.Email}</td>
                                    <td className="commentCRUD">
                                        <a onClick={(i) => this.handleCommentDelete(i)}>
                                            <i className="fa fa-trash" />
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

export default CommentList;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're on the right track. Get super familiar with map(), filter() and reduce().

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the index `i`, not the right way. Also i would prefer to pass `id` rather than `index`. Here is how you can do that:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class CommentList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            comments: []
        };
        this.handleCommentDelete = this.handleCommentDelete.bind(this);
    }
    handleCommentDelete(id) {
        let comments = this.state.comments.filter(comment => comment.id !== id);
        this.setState({
            comments: comments
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <table className="commentList">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.props.data.map(comment => {
                            return (
                                <tr className="comment" key={comment.Id}>
                                    <td className="commentId">{comment.Id}</td>
                                    <td className="commentName">{comment.Name}</td>
                                    <td className="commentPhone">{comment.Phone}</td>
                                    <td className="commentEmail">{comment.Email}</td>
                                    <td className="commentCRUD">
                                        <a onClick={() => this.handleCommentDelete(comment.Id)}>
                                            <i className="fa fa-trash" />
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

export default CommentList;
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Getting closer--but in ```let comments = this.state.comments.filter(comment.id !== id);```, comment is not defined.

Comment: My Bad. Answer Updated.